# Soundpool music does not play and Dialog disappears on pressing Positive button

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, soundpool

In the below code I am facing two problems.

1. **Soundpool does not play when the dialog appears when alarm fires. While the dialog is visible and I press "recent apps" button , I can find the dialog is shown as an app in the list and when I click on that, the sound plays and dialog appears.** But still there are some error messages captured in Log**. I'm not able to understand the Log message. I have included the log message. Please help me in understanding the log.
2. I am trying to run a countdown timer in my dialog box. When I press the "start" button I want to display the counter in a textView. But when I click the "start" button, the dialog disappears. **how do I make then dialog visible even when start button is pressed?**

   ```
   public class Notifier extends Activity {
   SoundPool sp = null;
   int explosion = 0;
   SharedPreferences storedata;
   public static final String filename = "Hydrate_Quantity_Data";
   float latest_quantity;

   AlertDialog alertDialog;

   public void returnValueFromSharedPreferences() {

   storedata = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
   latest_quantity = storedata.getFloat("latest_quantity", 0);

   }

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   // setTheme(android.R.style.theme_dialog);
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
   explosion = sp.load(this, R.raw.hydrate, 1);



            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder =
                                     new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   final TextView edittext = new TextView(this);
   edittext.setText("Press 'Start' to begin Countdown");
   alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("its time");
   alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("for 20 seconds");
   alertDialogBuilder.setView(edittext);
   alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

   alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Start", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
           // What ever you want to do with the value
               new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
                   @Override
                   public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                       edittext.setText("00:"+ (millisUntilFinished/1000));

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onFinish() {
                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                   }


               }.start();


       }
   });

   alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

           alertDialog.cancel();
       }
   });

   alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
   alertDialog.show();


   @Override
   protected void onStart() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onStart();
       if (explosion != 0) {
           sp.play(explosion, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
       }
       returnValueFromSharedPreferences();
   }
      }
   ```

**The LOG:**

> 09-02 00:20:32.390: W/System(17954): ClassLoader referenced unknown
>   path: /data/app/com.AkDev.healthify-2/lib/arm64  09-02 00:20:32.392:
>   V/Monotype(17954): SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app =
>   com.AkDev.healthify  09-02 00:20:32.396: V/Monotype(17954):
>   Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default  09-02
>   00:20:32.407: V/Monotype(17954): SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app =
>   com.AkDev.healthify  09-02 00:20:32.407: V/Monotype(17954):
>   Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default  09-02
>   00:20:32.488: V/BoostFramework(17954): mAcquireFunc method = public
>   int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquire(int,int[])  09-02
>   00:20:32.488: V/BoostFramework(17954): mReleaseFunc method = public
>   int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockRelease()  09-02
>   00:20:32.488: V/BoostFramework(17954): mAcquireTouchFunc method =
>   public int
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquireTouch(android.view.MotionEvent,android.util.DisplayMetrics,int,int[])
>   09-02 00:20:32.488: V/BoostFramework(17954): mIOPStart method = public
>   int
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStart(int,java.lang.String)
>   09-02 00:20:32.488: V/BoostFramework(17954): mIOPStop method = public
>   int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStop()  09-02
>   00:20:32.530: V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@b3a6454  09-02 00:20:32.531:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@f667ffd  09-02 00:20:32.757:
>   D/OpenGLRenderer(17954): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true  09-02
>   00:20:32.949: I/Adreno-EGL(17954): : EGL
>   1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8916_64_LA.BR.1.2.6_RB1__release_AU
>   (Ia10634f51b)  09-02 00:20:32.949: I/Adreno-EGL(17954): OpenGL ES
>   Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05  09-02 00:20:32.949:
>   I/Adreno-EGL(17954): Build Date: 01/04/16 Mon 09-02 00:20:32.949:
>   I/Adreno-EGL(17954): Local Branch: mybranch17585849  09-02
>   00:20:32.949: I/Adreno-EGL(17954): Remote Branch:
>   quic/LA.BR.1.2.6_rb1.7 09-02 00:20:32.949: I/Adreno-EGL(17954): Local
>   Patches: NONE 09-02 00:20:32.949: I/Adreno-EGL(17954): Reconstruct
>   Branch: NOTHING  09-02 00:20:32.958: I/OpenGLRenderer(17954):
>   Initialized EGL, version 1.4  09-02 00:20:33.047:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@38d404e  09-02 00:20:33.049:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@710556f  09-02 00:20:33.050:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@ed6627c  09-02 00:20:33.051:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@b31e705  09-02 00:20:33.051:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@b81135a  09-02 00:20:34.200:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@66eee81  09-02 00:20:34.321:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@9e489d6  09-02 00:20:34.321:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@9d21457  09-02 00:20:34.325:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@df76d62  09-02 00:20:34.325:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@1799ef3  09-02 00:20:34.327:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@f62fdae  09-02 00:20:34.327:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@905374f  09-02 00:20:34.380:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@925fcc8  09-02 00:20:34.380:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@2e1c161  09-02 00:20:35.090:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@63ab79c  09-02 00:20:35.092:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@999e5a5  09-02 00:20:35.093:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@d1d3d7a  09-02 00:20:35.095:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@48a892b  09-02 00:20:35.096:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@709b188  09-02 00:20:35.444:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@a683721  09-02 00:20:36.100:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@3b1b746  09-02 00:20:36.207:
>   V/Monotype(17954): SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app =
>   com.AkDev.healthify  09-02 00:20:36.207: V/Monotype(17954):
>   Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default  09-02
>   00:20:36.211: V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@ec201d2  09-02 00:20:36.211:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@f94f2a3  09-02 00:20:36.818:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@5ced132  09-02 00:20:37.999:
>   W/InputEventReceiver(17954): Attempted to finish an input event but
>   the input event receiver has already been disposed.  09-02
>   00:20:49.686: V/Monotype(17954): SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app =
>   com.AkDev.healthify  09-02 00:20:49.687: V/Monotype(17954):
>   Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default  09-02
>   00:20:49.811: V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@92d6130  09-02 00:20:49.811:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@70f31a9  09-02 00:20:49.831:
>   W/SoundPool(17954):   sample 1 not READY  09-02 00:20:49.855:
>   E/WVMExtractor(17954): Failed to open libwvm.so: dlopen failed:
>   library "libwvm.so" not found  09-02 00:20:49.901:
>   V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Sniff Start  09-02 00:20:49.901:
>   V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): amount of data read at start 1024 
>   09-02 00:20:49.901: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Parser_Flags ==
>   33ffff  09-02 00:20:49.901: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): SniffOGG
>   ===>  09-02 00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Updated nDataRead value after format 16 check is 1024  09-02 00:20:49.934:
>   V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Didn't match the sniff <=== status = 1,
>   formattocheck 16   09-02 00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954):
>   SniffAVI ===>  09-02 00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954):
>   Updated nDataRead value after format 6 check is 1024  09-02
>   00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Didn't match the sniff
>   <=== status = 5, formattocheck 6   09-02 00:20:49.934:
>   V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): SniffAC3 ===> 09-02 00:20:49.934:
>   V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Updated nDataRead value after format 1
>   check is 1024  09-02 00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954):
>   Didn't match the sniff <=== status = 1, formattocheck 1   09-02
>   00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): SniffASF ===>  09-02
>   00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Updated nDataRead value
>   after format 5 check is 1024  09-02 00:20:49.934:
>   V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Didn't match the sniff <=== status = 1,
>   formattocheck 5   09-02 00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954):
>   SniffAMRNB ===>  09-02 00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954):
>   Updated nDataRead value after format 3 check is 1024  09-02
>   00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Didn't match the sniff
>   <=== status = 1, formattocheck 3   09-02 00:20:49.934:
>   V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): SniffAMRWB ===>  09-02 00:20:49.934:
>   V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Updated nDataRead value after format 4
>   check is 1024  09-02 00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954):
>   Didn't match the sniff <=== status = 1, formattocheck 4   09-02
>   00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): SniffMKAV ===>  09-02
>   00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Updated nDataRead value
>   after format 14 check is 1024  09-02 00:20:49.934:
>   V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Didn't match the sniff <=== status = 1,
>   formattocheck 14   09-02 00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954):
>   Sniff3GP ===>  09-02 00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954):
>   Updated nDataRead value after format 10 check is 1024  09-02
>   00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Didn't match the sniff
>   <=== status = 1, formattocheck 10   09-02 00:20:49.934:
>   V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): SniffQCP ===>  09-02 00:20:49.934:
>   V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Updated nDataRead value after format 17
>   check is 1024  09-02 00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954):
>   Didn't match the sniff <=== status = 1, formattocheck 17   09-02
>   00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): SniffFLAC ===>  09-02
>   00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Updated nDataRead value
>   after format 9 check is 1024  09-02 00:20:49.934:
>   V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Didn't match the sniff <=== status = 1,
>   formattocheck 9   09-02 00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954):
>   SniffFLV ===>  09-02 00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954):
>   Updated nDataRead value after format 23 check is 1024  09-02
>   00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Didn't match the sniff
>   <=== status = 1, formattocheck 23   09-02 00:20:49.934:
>   V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): SniffMP2TS ===>  09-02 00:20:49.934:
>   V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Updated nDataRead value after format 13
>   check is 1024  09-02 00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954):
>   Didn't match the sniff <=== status = 1, formattocheck 13   09-02
>   00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Sniff3G2 ===>  09-02
>   00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Updated nDataRead value
>   after format 11 check is 1024  09-02 00:20:49.934:
>   V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Didn't match the sniff <=== status = 1,
>   formattocheck 11   09-02 00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954):
>   SniffMPEG2PS ===>  09-02 00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954):
>   Updated nDataRead value after format 12 check is 1024  09-02
>   00:20:49.934: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Didn't match the sniff
>   <=== status = 1, formattocheck 12  09-02 00:20:49.934:
>   V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): SniffAAC ===>  09-02 00:20:49.935:
>   V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Return status after 1st call 1, size
>   8202  09-02 00:20:49.935: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Didn't match
>   the sniff <=== status = 1, formattocheck 2   09-02 00:20:49.935:
>   V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): SniffMP3 ===>  09-02 00:20:49.935:
>   V/QComExtractorFactory(17954): Return status after 1st call 0, size
>   8202  09-02 00:20:49.935: V/QComExtractorFactory(17954):  SniffMP3
>   success<===   09-02 00:20:49.935: I/QComExtractorFactory(17954):
>   Sniff: Set key to use qti parser  09-02 00:20:49.942:
>   I/ExtendedExtractor(17954): QTIParser is prefered  09-02 00:20:49.943:
>   V/QComExtractorFactory(17954):  instantiate MMParserExtractor   09-02
>   00:20:49.943: I/ExtendedExtractor(17954): ExtendedExtractor::create
>   0x556c0a0cd0  09-02 00:20:49.943: I/ExtendedExtractor(17954):
>   ExtendedExtractor::updateExtractor: Use default QTI parser   09-02
>   00:20:49.943: E/MM_OSAL(17954): FileSource::FileSource  09-02
>   00:20:49.943: E/MM_OSAL(17954): FileSource::FileSource m_bEveryThingOK
>   1 09-02 00:20:49.943: E/MM_OSAL(17954): MM_File_Create failed .Efs
>   Error No -1 , File Name /data/mmosal_logmask.cfg , Mode 0  09-02
>   00:20:49.943: E/MM_OSAL(17954): Open or read fail on
>   /data/mmosal_logmask.cfg. Possible permission denied issue. Looking
>   for /data/misc/media/mmosal_logmask.cfg  09-02 00:20:49.943:
>   E/MM_OSAL(17954): MM_File_Create failed .Efs Error No -1 , File Name
>   /data/misc/media/mmosal_logmask.cfg , Mode 0  09-02 00:20:49.968:
>   I/OMXClient(17954): Using client-side OMX mux.  09-02 00:20:50.255:
>   E/MMParserExtractor(17954): FileSource::FILE_SOURCE_DATA_END   09-02
>   00:20:51.701: V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@29d86a7  09-02 00:20:54.078:
>   V/BoostFramework(17954): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@e57dabb  09-02 00:20:54.270:
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper(17954): beginBatchEdit on inactive
>   InputConnection  09-02 00:20:54.270: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(17954):
>   endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection  09-02 00:20:54.307:
>   V/RenderScript(17954): 0x556c0bf080 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4  09-02
>   00:20:54.315: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(17954): beginBatchEdit on
>   inactive InputConnection  09-02 00:20:54.316:
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper(17954): endBatchEdit on inactive
>   InputConnection